# Set new startTime and endTime on videojs

Tags: pdk

My problem is that I'm trying to reposition the start time and end time on the seek bar. My use case is this: i'm watching the video with a progress bar that go from 0 to 300 sec (e.g.). When i arrive at 200 sec, i want to set start time at 200 sec so the marker go to new 0 (old 200) and the stream continues. I'm using the last version of videojs and my code is not necessary because is almost native.